# Fdisk cylinder doesn't match device format

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, fdisk

I plugged in a USB device into my computer and ran fdisk on the partition, giving the following:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.9 GB, 16944988160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2060 cylinders, total 33095680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1b45097d

Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           0     2009087     1004544    0  Empty
/dev/sdb2         1943108     1947779        2336   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

I was under the impression that the start and end number enumerated the cylinders being used. Why are the numbers so high in this case, way beyond 2060? What are they actually counting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHS addressing has been entirely made up nonsense for decades, so a few years ago `fdisk` finally switched the default reporting units to sectors.